# How to make a textview scroll vertically?

Tags: java, android, textview

I have `textview` that include a large text and fill the parent layout.but i don't want to use `Scrollview` and i want to change the `textview` properties. How Can I scroll the `textview` Vertically?

Comment: Please share the code of your layout and add a screenshot of your problem.

Answer (score 3):

You can make `textview` as a child of `scrollView`, and make `textview` as height as wrap content.

Comment: This is the best answer I read about how to make a textview scrollable. I tried everything and it wouldn't work until I set height of textview as wrap_content.

Answer (score 1):

One general way to do this would be wrap your top level layout in a `<ScrollView>`, something like this:

```
<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/yourScrollView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="60dp">
     <LinearLayout
         android:id="@+id/yourMainLayout"
         android:orientation="vertical"
         android:padding="12dp"                 <!-- add your other content here -->
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content">
     </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Then, inside the above `LinearLayout` you may add one or more `TextView`.

Answer (score 0):

In the `textview` xml Add this:

```
android:scrollbars = "vertical"
```